# Rstudio, trying to pull data from EML.R into a table and I get error: Error: Columns 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, and 18 more must be named

Tags: r, tibble

I'm pretty new to R and I've trying to follow a tutorial.

Here are the steps they want us to follow.

```html
# INSTALL AND LOAD PACKAGES ################################

# Load contributed packages with pacman
pacman::p_load(pacman, tidyverse, XML2R)
# pacman: for loading/unloading packages
# tidyverse: for so many reasons
# XML2R: for working with XML data

# GET DATA & RESTRUCTURE ###################################

# Data from http://ergast.com/mrd/
# File: http://ergast.com/api/f1/1954/results/1.xml
# Right click to "View page source" and see raw XML

# Import XML data from web (must be online)
df <- "http://ergast.com/api/f1/1954/results/1.xml" %>%
  XML2Obs() %>%
  collapse_obs() %>%
  print()

# See variable (node) names and IDs
df %>%
  names() %>%
  print()

# EXTRACT & COMBINE DATA ###################################

# Extract data and save as tibble
df %<>%  # %<>% is the compound assignment pipe operator
  as_tibble() %>%                        # Save as tibble
  select(                                # Select data
    Race = matches("RaceName"),          # Get race name
    FirstName = matches("GivenName"),    # Get first name
    LastName = matches("FamilyName"),    # Get last name
    Team = matches("Constructor//Name")  # Get team name
  ) %>% 
  print()  # Each column is a list with two values (oops)
```

I'm struggling with the step "EXTRACT & COMBINE DATA"

I'm getting the error: Error: Columns 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, and 18 more must be named.

I have tried a few options such as, .name_repair and it doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to SO. It's easier to help you if your question is  reproducible with your inputs, code and expected output that can be used to test possible solutions [reprex] and [ask] for guidance.

Comment: @Peter Thanks for the help, really new to this so any guidance is well received. I have updated the question to add as much detail as possible. Please let me know if that is okay.